# How to reset the TPMS Warning light on 2018 Hyundai Elantra

Tags: hyundai, elantra, tire-pressure-monitoring-system

The TPMS warning light came on on my wife's 2018 Elantra.  One tire was slightly below the trigger level and I easily pumped it back up.  However the warning light still refuses to go out even after driving for various times at various speeds (up to and including  1/2 hour at 75 mph)

The users manual states (in the "Changing a tire with TPMS" section)

> Once the original tire equipped with a tire pressure monitoring sensor
> is reinflated to the recommended pressure and reinstalled on the
> vehicle, the Low Tire Pressure LCD position indicator and TPMS
> Malfunction Indicator will go off within a few minutes of driving

I googled for solutions to this and could't find a suitable answer.  Some Hyundai's apparently have a reset button under the steering wheel, but as far as I can tell this model doesn't.  Another video I saw (not in English), seemed to suggest connecting an OBD2 reader and using that to reset the light.  This is confusing me, as on my Subaru the light resets automatically when you start the car and drive for a bit if the pressures are above minimum.

So what is the solution to this?

---

Note that there is also a TPMS Malfunction Indicator that uses the same warning light on the dash.  The manual says that this is indicated by flashing the warning light for 1 minute before going solid after starting the car.  This light comes on solid and doesn't flash, so IMHO it is not indicating a system fault.

Comment: Did you check ALL of the tires when you filled the low one up? It could be there is more than one tire low.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Yes I checked all the tires, and pumped them all up to the same pressure.  But the TPMS is only indicating a single tire anyway.

Comment: Did you *overfill* them? I know on my wife's car (08 Azera LTD), if they are too hard, the TPMS light will come on as well. I think the system gives me about +/- 5psi (might be less) ... I would bet the Elantra has the same basic system on it.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 That's a whole different question that I'm planning to ask about.  I live at 7,000 feet and the TPMS system isn't calibrated for that.  It generally reads about 4 psi low.  So I fill to 36 psi absolute, but the TPMS system sees this as 32 psi, which matches the requirements.  This is the recommended solution from multiple, local dealers.  But all 4 wheels were set to 36 psi absolute, and only 1 tire is showing as low.

Comment: Fair enough ... thanks for entertaining my questions.

Comment: I was just thinking you might be able to pull the ground strap and let the car sit without power for 30 mins. This might reset the TPMS. I've never heard of anyone doing this, but at least it might be worth a try.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Anything is worth a go, but I was hoping for something a bit less extreme.  I know i can take it to the dealership for a reset, but I'm trying to see what I can do myself

Comment: There is a tool to allow you to reset your TPMS. Depending on your pain threshold, you can purchase it. To me it's not uber expensive, but I don't have one (and I have a lot of tools, lol). Anyways, it is available. A typical OBDII scanner cannot help you here. You have to have a TPMS one in order to do the job. I don't know about the REALLY expensive ones (like Snap-On), which may do this for you, but the regularly priced OBDII scanners for us poor zhlubs won't work.

Comment: Have you checked your spare tire?  If it has a TPMS sensor that could be alerting you.  If this isn't the issue, take the car into a tire center and see if they can fix the issue.  They have the tooling to link the sensors to the vehicle, and it could even be a bad sensor.

Comment: @MattAnderson It was definitely the reported tire that had a low pressure.  And the car was taken to the deanship where the alarm was reset.  However I'm still looking for ways in which I can reset it myself.